# Outside click event listener isnt working: Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am implementing a custom side panel that opens up from the right. I am able to achieve show and hide of the panel on a click of a button. But I want the same thing to be hidden when i click outside. I am attaching the outside click handler, And when I do that it is not even showing up. Can someone help

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sliding-pane-v2-4xuj57?file=/src/SlideDrawer.jsx:100-173

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function SlideDrawer({ show, setDrawerOpen }) {
  const sideMenuRef = useRef(null);

  const onOutsideClick = useCallback(() => {
    setDrawerOpen(false);
  }, [setDrawerOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", onOutsideClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", onOutsideClick);
  }, [onOutsideClick]);

  return (
    <div ref={sideMenuRef} className={`panel ${show && "slidein"}`}>
      I am sliding
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SlideDrawer from "./SlideDrawer.jsx";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <SlideDrawer show={drawerOpen} setDrawerOpen={setDrawerOpen} />
      <button onClick={() => setDrawerOpen((prev) => !prev)}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Since you tagged your question with ```javascript``` I made a solution here https://jsfiddle.net/2z74a5gt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens:

If you click the button, `drawerOpen` is set to true and immediately set to false again. You can verify by adding

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(drawerOpen)
  }, [drawerOpen])
```

to index.js.

To fix this, you'll need to check if the click targeted the button in your eventListener.

You can solve it by giving the button an id:

```js
      <button id="openPanelButton" onClick={() =>setDrawerOpen((prev) => !prev)}>Click me!</button>
```

and then checking the click like this:

```js
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function SlideDrawer({ show, setDrawerOpen }) {
  const sideMenuRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.target.id !== "openPanelButton" && event.target !== sideMenuRef.current) {
      setDrawerOpen(false);
    }
  }, [setDrawerOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
  }, [handleClick]);

  return (
    <div ref={sideMenuRef} className={`panel ${show && "slidein"}`}>
      I am sliding
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how do we achieve this?

Comment: I edited my answer above to include a solution.

Comment: still on outside click the the panel isnt getting hidden

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully. I edited the answer again.

Comment: Hey sorry, I dont want the child to be dependent on id ? Can this be solved in any other way

Comment: You can use a ref just like with SideMenu and then pass it as a prop down to into SlideDrawer

Answer (score 0):

To achieve behavior that you want, you need to change event that you are looking for from "click" to "mousedown" like this:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", onOutsideClick);
```

This way, same click wouldn't trigger open and close at the same time.

Also update your onClick that open your drawer and check if it already opened.

That way it will work

Comment: still isnt working, can you edit the sandbox or post the edited snippet here?

Comment: Take a look here. Your codesandbox also doesn't worked because you rendered on root element in wrong way. Here is working sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sliding-pane-v2-forked-yo7505